# Generating unique random string for identifying a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a requirement to be able to identify a record in a table, in this case a user table, by a unique key which does not give away the ordering of the records in the table.

Currently I have primary key field and the routes that are generated look like:

```
/users/1
```

However, I'd like to be able to generate a route like:

```
/users/kfjslncdk
```

I can wire everything up on the route side, database side etc.. but I'm not sure what the best way to generate a unique string identifier would be in rails.  I'd like do something like:

```
before_save :create_unique_identifier

def create_unique_identifier
    self.unique_identifier = ... magic goes here ...
end
```

I was thinking I could use the first part of a guid created using UUIDTools, but I'd need to check to make sure it was unique before saving the user.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 59):

```
before_create :create_unique_identifier

def create_unique_identifier
  loop do
    self. unique_identifier = SecureRandom.hex(5) # or whatever you chose like UUID tools
    break unless self.class.exists?(:unique_identifier => unique_identifier)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Ruby 1.9 [includes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-uuid) a built-in UUID generator: `SecureRandom.uuid`

Answer (score 5):

- [uuid](http://github.com/assaf/uuid)
- [uuidtools](http://github.com/sporkmonger/uuidtools)
- [How to create small, unique tokens in Ruby](https://gist.github.com/mbajur/2aba832a6df3fc31fe7a82d3109cb626)

Comment: I believe UUID was already known by the asker (see the q. text) ;). But +1 for the third link.

Answer (score 4):

Another possiblity is to use `SecureRandom.base64` which in comparison to `hex` additionally use capitalized letters and “+”, “/”, “=”. [Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/Random/Formatter.html#method-i-base64).

Example:

```
def generate_identifier
  begin
    uid = SecureRandom.base64(8)
  end while self.class.exists?(uid: uid)
  self.uid = uid
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Save yourself the trouble from storing the obfuscated id and simply encode the id with base 62 (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) but custom define the order of the "digits". This will make it very complicated to figure out the order.

I once wrote something a class that does that (might need some refactoring): https://gist.github.com/4058176